# Python subplot ¿cómo puedo cubrir todo el intervalo de datos con el área amarilla?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

me gustaría hacer una gráfica con los datos, el mejor ajuste y una region con dos sigma (desviacion standart) alrededor del mejor ajuste.
Obtuve una gráfica, pero me muestra sólo una pequeña porción en color amarillo. ¿cómo puedo cubrir todo el intervalo de mis datos con la área amarilla?
envio mi código para recibir.

gracias por su amable ayuda y saludos

Hi, 
I want to plot in a single graph the data, the best fit and a region two sigma(standar desviation) around the best fit.
I get this graph, but it show only a small portion (yellow area)
 ¿how can I cover  the whole range of my data with the yellow dashed area? 
this is my code

```
import statistics
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from scipy import stats
plt.style.use('classic')

# Read data
SEDsj = pd.read_csv('data.txt',header = None, delim_whitespace=True)
ys=SEDsj.ix[:,1]
xs=SEDsj.ix[:,0]

# filter for data 
mask = (ys > 40)

#best fit
def best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys):
    m = (((mean(xs[mask])*mean(ys[mask])) - mean(xs[mask]*ys[mask])) /
         ((mean(xs[mask])*mean(xs[mask])) - mean(xs[mask]*xs[mask])))

    b = mean(ys[mask]) - m*mean(xs[mask])

    return m, b

m, b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys)


regression_line = [(m*x)+b for x in xs]
style.use('ggplot')
std_err = stats.linregress(xs[mask],ys[mask])

###region in 2 sigma area
logX = (xs + 4.37)/1.106  #Model
sigma1 = np.std(ys[mask]) #standar desviation
y3 = np.asarray(regression_line) - 2*sigma1  # lower limit 2 sigma
y4 = np.asarray(regression_line) + 2*sigma1  # upper limit 2 sigma

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xs[mask],ys[mask], '*r', label='data') #data
ax.plot(xs,logX, '-b', label='Other fit') #Model
ax.plot(xs, regression_line,'--g',label = 'Best fit') #best fit

ax.fill_between(xs, y3, y4, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5,
                label='2 sigma range') #dashed area 

ax.axis('equal')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False) 
plt.show()
```

I get this [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
I want something like this [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]